# Selenium Twitter java

Tags: java, selenium, twitter

I'm tryng to get connected to my twitter account using Selenium Webdriver

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
driver.get("https://www.twitter.com/login/");

WebElement formElement = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("form.signin"));
List<WebElement> allFormChildElements = formElement.findElements(By.cssSelector("input"));

    for(WebElement item : allFormChildElements )
    {       
          System.out.println("<"+item.getTagName()+"> "+ item.getAttribute("name") ); 
        switch(item.getAttribute("name")) {
            case "session[username_or_email]": 
                item.sendKeys(username);
                break;
            case "session[password]":
                item.sendKeys(password);
                break;
        }      
    }
```

But i'm getting this error log :

```
<input> session[username_or_email]
Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
Command duration or timeout: 38 millisecon
```

ds

I don't understand because it is printing the name of the input, why is not visible ?
Any ideas ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found that By inspecting the DOM of the twitter login page has two forms having almost same properties and three username and password fields are found.That's why you're getting `ElementNotVisibleException`[See Image]

[image]

So for that you have to go with relative xpath or css selectors or implement a logic for that .I'm proving two ways you can handle that situation

And I don't know why you are iterating over all the input fields and then finding the element by checking its attributes.You can simply call `driver.findElements(By.name())`

**Relative Xpath**

As I found that the input inside the `@class` `signin-wrapper` is the visible one,I've gone for this xpath

```
driver.get("https://twitter.com/login/");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='signin-wrapper']//input[@name='session[username_or_email]']")).sendKeys("viaxpath");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='signin-wrapper']//input[@name='session[password]']")).sendKeys("viaxpath");
```

**Get the Visible Element**

As the name implies it will find all the elements and return the element that is only visible

```
driver.get("https://twitter.com/login/");
 getVisibleElement(driver, "session[username_or_email]").sendKeys("viavisibleName");
 getVisibleElement(driver, "session[password]").sendKeys("viavisibleName");

public static WebElement getVisibleElement(WebDriver driver, String name) {
    List<WebElement> elements = driver.findElements(By.name(name));
    for (WebElement element : elements) {
        if (element.isDisplayed()) {
            return element;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```