# Selenium Webdriver: cssselector

Tags: selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver, automation, css-selectors

I am trying to do SignIn for [this](http://way2automation.com/way2auto_jquery/index.php). In it click on 'SignIn' which I have done it successfully. Now when trying to type in Username/Password using Xpath it shows exception which says

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.ElementNotVisibleException: element not visible

code is :-

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='load_form']/fieldset[1]/input")).sendKeys("test123");
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='load_form']/fieldset[2]/input")).sendKeys("test123");
```

I know this `Xpath` is same as used in `SignUp` form, so what are the other ways to locate these two fields? How we can use it by using `cssselector`?
Thanks for the help in advance.

Comment: [Check this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31683299/3122133)

Comment: This is based on PowerShell? What is the target platform and language used?

Answer (score 1):

Go One Level up on finding the relative xpath with

```
//div[@id='login']/form[@id='load_form']//input[@name='username']
//div[@id='login']/form[@id='load_form']//input[@name='password']
```

Comment: Thank u so much. I am new to web driver and will be really helpful if you will share some tutorial regarding it

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
 //For Username
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='username'])[2]")).sendKeys("username test");
//or
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login > #load_form > fieldset > input[name='usernam']")).click();   

//For password
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("(//input[@name='password'])[2]")).sendKeys("password test");
//or
        driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#login > #load_form > fieldset > input[name='password']")).click();
```

the above codes are working for me.

Comment: Thank u so much. I am new to web driver and will be really helpful if you will share some tutorial regarding it

Comment: just google selenium webdriver tutorial @Ghanghar there are many good websites

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two elements found by provided `xpath`, and it works with first found element which is invisible as your exception saying, you should try using `cssSelector` as below :-

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#login input[name = 'username']")).sendKeys("test123");
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div#login input[name = 'password']")).sendKeys("test123");
```

**Note**:- For learning about `cssSelector` follow [this url](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp) and for `xPath` follow [this url](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp)

I'm suggesting you before selenium execution with the locator you need to sure that using locator is correct and returns single or multiple element at your **browser console by pressing f12**. for verify `xPath` you should use `$x("your xpath expression")` and for `cssSelector` you should use `document.querySelector("your css selector expression")`..

Hope it will help you..:)

Comment: Thank u so much..!!
I am new to webdriver and will be really helpful if you will share some tutorial regarding it

Comment: @PGhanghar you welocme..glad to help you..:)

Comment: @PGhanghar follow this for cssSelector http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp

Comment: @PGhanghar and this for xpath http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xpath_axes.asp..